# Writing Firebase database after app is swiped from recent list

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-service

I need to write three items of data in Firebase Realtime Database in case the user kill the app 
from recent list while it's still running; I implemented a service in order to 
update the database when `onTaskRemoved` is called.
In the manifest the service is declared with the option `android:stopWithTask="false"`

Here is the service

```
public class ServiceAppMonitoring extends Service {
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);

        FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        SharedPreferences mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

        //Get some datas from Shared Preferences...

        String path1 = "first/node/path";

        mDatabase.getReference(path1).setValue(false);

        if (condition) {
            // Compose array of datas
            List<Object> data2 = Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ ... });

            String path2 = "second/node/path";

            mDatabase.getReference(path2).setValue(data2);

            // Compose array of datas
            List<Object> data3 = Arrays.asList(new Object[]{ ... });

            String path3 = "third/node/path";

            mDatabase.getReference(path3).setValue(data3);

            stopSelf();
        } else {
            stopSelf();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }
}
```

Strangely only the first instruction is successful, the other two seem to be ignored... at least no data is written into database.

Further I've noticed another "unusual" behaviour, if I arrange all the `DatabaseReference`s in the 
following way:

```
    mDatabase.getReference("first").child("node").child("path").setValue(false);
```

no one of the instructions end up writing into database, to get (at least) the first one working I've to arrange this way:

```
    mDatabase.getReference("first/node/path").setValue(false);
```

Can anybody kindly help me to understand why this happens?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because Firebase operations are asynchronous, and return immediately before the writes are complete.  `onTaskRemved` is going to return before either of the database writes fully finish.

I'm guessing that your app process is going to die very soon, if not immediately, after `onTaskRemved` returns.  This means that your database writes might not finish.  Android doesn't know that these writes are pending, and it's not going to wait for them.

Since you don't have way from your service to tell Android to wait for these writes, you will have to schedule them for later.  I suggest looking into using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) to schedule the writes to happen in the background, whenever Android allows it.  It might not be immediate, but WorkManager will make sure that any scheduled tasks will eventually complete.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for your reply, I'll look into `WorkManager`. I was suspicious it can be about timing but, when I swipe it out from recent list, even if app is closed service wouldn't since I set `stopWithTask=false`... or do I miss something? I put some logs into code and actually app's `onDestroy` came before `onTaskRemoved` but it was something I expected.

Comment: The issue isn't the timing of any of the android callbacks. The problem is that you have no guarantee how long the async database operations will take. setValue returns immediately, and the value gets written some unknown amount of time later.

Answer (score 0):

Hey based on your answer I updated a small thing on database from onTaskRemoved like this
I already initialized the DatabaseReference in the onCreate method
DatabaseReference temp = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference().child("temp");

and in onTaskRemoved
temp.setValue(true);

this is getting executed and I added a onchange listener in onCreate method to listen for this values change and it worked like a charm. If you don't understand anything feel free to ask and let me know how you got over this problem:)

EDIT:
This is not working in all devices...

EDIT AGAIN: I simply used on Destroy method in my service and killed the service after completing the task and is working for  now...

EDIT AGAIN AND AGAIN: OnDestroy is not working in android 6 or below I guess. I tested in Android 6 and it didnt work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](/tour)